# Python create date string with timezone out of multiple rows of data in CSV

Tags: python, string, csv, datetime, timezone

In a python script: Looking to create a date string that looks like "2020-07-20T13:30:00-0700" out of 3 columns of a CSV file: "7/20/2020", "13:30", "America/Los_Angeles"

Examples of data in CSV in picture below

[image]

What would be the best way to deal with creating these strings with that last timezone piece considering I'm only given "America/Los_Angeles" or "America/Detroit" ect.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient option to manipulate spreadsheet data is to use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) package. Here, you would read the csv to a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), combine date and time columns [to a `datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) column and localize to the given timezone. Ex:

```
from io import StringIO # this is just to get the example running...
import pandas as pd

s = """date,time,timezone
7/14/2020,13:30,America/Los_Angeles
7/16/2020,4:30,America/Chicago"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# create datetime column from date and time
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+' '+df['time'])

# localize to timezone
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['datetime'].tz_localize(r['timezone']), axis=1)
# df
#         date   time             timezone                   datetime
# 0  7/14/2020  13:30  America/Los_Angeles  2020-07-14 13:30:00-07:00
# 1  7/16/2020   4:30      America/Chicago  2020-07-16 04:30:00-05:00
```

If you want an ISO8601 compatible string output, you can create such a column like

```
# to ISO 8601 string format
df['ISO_dt'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda t: t.isoformat())
# df['ISO_dt']
# 0    2020-07-14T13:30:00-07:00
# 1    2020-07-16T04:30:00-05:00
# Name: ISO_dt, dtype: object
```

---

For completeness, here's a way to do it without `pandas`. Load the data using a `DictReader` from the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, parse to `datetime`, set the timezone and extract the ISO string:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
 
# read csv to dict
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(s))   
data = {}
for row in reader:
    for c, v in row.items():
        data.setdefault(c, []).append(v)
        
# combine date and time, set timezone and get ISO string        
isostrings = []        
for d, t, timezone in zip(data['date'], data['time'], data['timezone']):
    isostrings.append(
                      datetime.strptime(d + t, '%m/%d/%Y%H:%M')
                      .replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz(timezone))
                      .isoformat()
                      )
  
# isostrings
# ['2020-07-14T13:30:00-07:00', '2020-07-16T04:30:00-05:00']
```